# "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted" error when simply sending image to icloud

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, icloud

Im simply trying to upload this image to iCloud. It keeps giving me the error "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted". I took this code right out of the Document Based App Programming Guide and I believe I've set all my certificates, identifiers, profiles, and entitlements correctly. Any help would be much appreciated. This is insanely frustrating.

```
#import "docx.h"

@implementation docx

-(IBAction)test:(id)sender{

    NSURL *src = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/rjm226/Desktop/jh.jpg"];
        NSLog(@"%@", src);

    NSURL *dest = NULL;

    NSURL *ubiquityContainerURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                    URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]
                                   URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

    if (ubiquityContainerURL == nil) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: NSLocalizedString(@"iCloud does not appear to be configured.", @""),
                              NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey, nil];

        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Application" code:404
                                         userInfo:dict];

        [self presentError:error modalForWindow:[self windowForSheet] delegate:nil didPresentSelector:NULL contextInfo:NULL];

        return;
    }

    dest = [ubiquityContainerURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:
            [src lastPathComponent]];

    //Move file to iCloud

    dispatch_queue_t globalQueue =
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(globalQueue, ^(void) {

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

        NSError *error = nil;
        // Move the file.

        BOOL success = [fileManager setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:src
                                   destinationURL:dest error:&error];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            if (! success) {
                [self presentError:error modalForWindow:[self windowForSheet]
                          delegate:nil didPresentSelector:NULL contextInfo:NULL];
            }
        });
    });
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

> *This is insanely frustrating.*

Welcome to iCloud. You'll get used to that feeling after a while. In the meantime though, you have other problems.

```
NSURL *src = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/rjm226/Desktop/jh.jpg"];
```

This is not going to give you a valid URL, which is going to be a problem. What you need is:

```
NSURL *src = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/rjm226/Desktop/jh.jpg"];
```

That will give you a valid `file://` URL.

Comment: Thanks so much. This did not solve the problem, but was certainly an error in the code.